# Having issue with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having an MySQL issue and here is the query:

```
SELECT        JAN.Sales_Phase, JAN.January, FEB.Febuary, MAR.March, APR.April, MAY.May, JUN.June, JUL.July, AUG.August, SEP.September, OCT.October, NOV.November, 
                         DEC.December
FROM            (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS January
                          FROM            MasterTable_TM
                          WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                    (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '1')
                          GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS JAN LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS Febuary
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_1
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '2')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS FEB ON FEB.Sales_Phase = JAN.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS March
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_2
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '3')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS MAR ON MAR.Sales_Phase = FEB.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS April
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_3
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '4')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS APR ON APR.Sales_Phase = MAR.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS May
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_4
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '5')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS MAY ON MAY.Sales_Phase = APR.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS June
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_5
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '6')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS JUN ON JUN.Sales_Phase = MAY.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS July
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_6
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '7')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS JUL ON JUL.Sales_Phase = JUN.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS August
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_7
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '8')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS AUG ON AUG.Sales_Phase = JUL.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS September
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_8
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '9')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS SEP ON SEP.Sales_Phase = AUG.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS October
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_9
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '10')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS OCT ON OCT.Sales_Phase = SEP.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS November
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_10
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '11')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS NOV ON NOV.Sales_Phase = OCT.Sales_Phase LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Sales_Phase, COALESCE (SUM(PO_Amount_USD), 0) AS December
                               FROM            MasterTable_TM AS MasterTable_TM_11
                               WHERE        (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR
                                                         (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '12')
                               GROUP BY Sales_Phase) AS DEC ON DEC.Sales_Phase = NOV.Sales_Phase
```

There is data record inside September and October but for the other month is not having data at all.
I tried to run this query but zero result is return. If I remove the other month and leaving only September and October on the query, there is result giving back to me.

How can it be done with showing the other month even if it is on null?
The COALESCE () function is used but it's like it is not functioning.

Comment: Could you edit your post and add table stucture with a few lines of data inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need so much join to implement the pivot, just group by and case like this:

```
SELECT Sales_Phase
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 1 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS January
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 2 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS Febuary
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 3 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS March
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 4 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS April
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 5 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS May
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 6 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS June
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 7 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS July
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 8 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS August
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 9 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS September
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 10 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS October
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 11 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS November
     , SUM(case PO_Month when 12 then PO_Amount_USD else 0 end) AS December
  FROM MasterTable_TM
 WHERE (Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') 
    OR (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') 
   AND (PO_Month between '1' and '12') -- these conditions do really make no sense, but leave it as the original sample code
 GROUP BY Sales_Phase
```

You have two problems in your query:

1. The first sub query will return nothing if no data in January, so the other left joins will return nothing obviously.
2. `(Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card') OR (Sales_Phase = 'PO Received') AND (PO_Month = '1')` was so confusing, if Sales_Phase = 'Credits Card' you want return data from all month? The priority of  `AND` is higer than `OR`

Comment: This is nice! Work out smoothly. Thanks! That Condition (PO_Month between '1' and '12') is not needed anymore.

Comment: @MistF I updated my answer about some problems, wish you could explain it.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I notice that problem too. After all, the January is empty so no data can be match with the join condition.
2. Hmmm, You just wake me up from this mistake. I want data on Both sales_phase. Thanks again. That should sum up the things.